# how to add % in setnumber notification android?

Tags: android, notifications

This is a daily PN by walnut app. How can they show % symbol where notification builder .setNumber method supports only int. How to achieve same programming ?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They don't use setNumber(), they use [setContentInfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentInfo(java.lang.CharSequence)), which fills the same location on the notification but accepts a `CharSequence` which can be any string you want including a number followed by a % sign.